# Run docker in an existing network namespace?

Tags: docker, bridge, namespaces, network-namespace

Would it be possible to run a docker container inside an existing namespace ?
I created a namespace using:
`ip netns add client`
Now I want to run a container (with a bridge or host network, whatever is possible) inside that namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, instead of running the container in a newly created namespace II can simply run processes in the namespace that docker created for that container. This is how: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-access-docker-containers-network-namespace-from-host/