# Run docker in pre-exisiting network namespaces

Tags: docker, docker-networking

I need to run a docker in a pre-existing namespace, which wasn't created by docker infrastructure. Is it possible to do ? I am aware of reusing another container option but as I mentioned the pre-existing ns wasn't created by one ( so answer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011214/run-docker-in-an-existing-network-namespace) question is irrelevant). I need solution for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your docker systemd unit file, you can find it via `systemctl status docker.service`

> ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
> Loaded: loaded (**/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service**; disabled; preset: disabled)

Modify the `[Service]` part of the unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
# This tells systemd to run dockerd in the network namespace
NetworkNamespacePath=/run/netns/ns_name
# This is the original docker command, it caused some issues for me
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
# This is the replacement if the default exec doesn't work
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// 
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

Now refresh the configs and start docker with

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

If you're lucky, you can now try running a docker container and it will just work. However, sometimes the configuration between containerd and docker doesn't work as smoothly and you will get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/sbin/tini": stat
> /sbin/tini: no such file or directory: unknown

This error appears to be from a misconfiguration between containerd and docker.
Open the `containerd` unit file and replace its `ExecStart` with the following:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/containerd --config=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
```

This will tell containerd to use docker's configuration and your containers should work after you reload the configs restart all the services.
Frankly, it is easier to just reboot the machine at this point.

As for what this does, we get an interesting series of effects.

- The `docker` executable talks to `dockerd` via a unix socket, so it does not matter what namespace you run `docker` or `docker-compose` commands from, as long as the socket is accessible.
- `containerd` is running in the default network namespace, which has all of the proper cgroups to create containers.
- `dockerd` is running inside your namespace, so it will create all network interfaces inside this namespace and all container networks will be generated inside this namespace by default.

As a final note, unless you setup a service to create your network namespace on boot, you will probably want to leave docker disabled and have a startup script create the namespace and then start docker.
In addition, you may need to run `chattr +i` on your unit files to prevent updates from overwriting your config changes.

Comment: I think the OP really meant he wanted a docker container to use an existing netns. I don't see how placing the docker daemon into one help. (If it does, wouldn't all containers be sharing one netns? Which would be a total mess?)